# CMake and MinGW - "The C Compiler is not able to compile a simple test program"

Tags: cmake, mingw

I am using CMake and MinGW-w64 64-bit to build. I have used this exact same setup with the same compiler on my other PC and it has worked. Not sure what's wrong.

I have the MinGW-w64 bin in my PATH. When I run cmake and do not specify the compiler path, it generates MinGW Makefiles successfully. However, when I specify the compiler (which I know does work, I got it from winlibs.com) it produces the following log. I am running Windows 10.

```
Detecting C compiler ABI info failed to compile with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Libraries/Projects/CMakeTest/build/MinGW-10.1.0-64-bit/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/MinGW/MinGW-10.1.0-64-bit/bin/mingw32-make.exe cmTC_a01cd/fast && C:/MinGW/MinGW-10.1.0-64-bit/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_a01cd.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_a01cd.dir/build

mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Libraries/Projects/CMakeTest/build/MinGW-10.1.0-64-bit/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_a01cd.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.obj

C:\MinGW\MinGW-10.1.0-64-bit\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe   -v -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_a01cd.dir\CMakeCCompilerABI.c.obj -c "C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.18\Modules\CMakeCCompilerABI.c"

Using built-in specs.

COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\MinGW-10.1.0-64-bit\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe

Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32

Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/R/winlibs64_10.1.0/inst_gcc-10.1.0/share/gcc --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-pkgversion='MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders' --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --enable-threads=posix --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-serial-configure --disable-bootstrap --enable-host-shared --enable-plugin --enable-default-ssp --disable-rpath --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-stabs --disable-symvers --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++,d --disable-gold --disable-nls --disable-stage1-checking --disable-win32-registry --disable-multilib --enable-ld --enable-libquadmath --enable-libada --enable-libssp --enable-libstdcxx --enable-lto --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libgomp --enable-graphite --enable-mingw-wildcard --with-mpc=/d/winlibs64_10.1.0/custombuilt --with-mpfr=/d/winlibs64_10.1.0/custombuilt --with-gmp=/d/winlibs64_10.1.0/custombuilt --with-isl=/d/winlibs64_10.1.0/custombuilt --enable-install-libiberty --enable-__cxa_atexit --without-included-gettext --with-diagnostics-color=auto --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-build-sysroot=/R/winlibs64_10.1.0/gcc-10.1.0/build_mingw/mingw-w64

Thread model: posix

Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd

gcc version 10.1.0 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 

COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles\cmTC_a01cd.dir\CMakeCCompilerABI.c.obj' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'

 c:/mingw/mingw-10.1.0-64-bit/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\mingw\mingw-10.1.0-64-bit\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/ -D_REENTRANT C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.18\Modules\CMakeCCompilerABI.c -quiet -dumpbase CMakeCCompilerABI.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase-strip CMakeFiles\cmTC_a01cd.dir\CMakeCCompilerABI.c.obj -version -o C:\Users\gvcal\AppData\Local\Temp\ccHRxkpy.s

GNU C17 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) version 10.1.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)

    compiled by GNU C version 10.1.0, GMP version 6.2.0, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.22.1-GMP



GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072

ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/mingw-10.1.0-64-bit/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/include"

ignoring nonexistent directory "R:/winlibs64_10.1.0/inst_gcc-10.1.0/share/gcc/include"

ignoring nonexistent directory "/R/winlibs64_10.1.0/inst_gcc-10.1.0/share/gcc/include"

ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/mingw-10.1.0-64-bit/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/include-fixed"

ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/mingw-10.1.0-64-bit/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"

ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw/include"

#include "..." search starts here:

#include <...> search starts here:

 c:\mingw\mingw-10.1.0-64-bit\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/include

 c:\mingw\mingw-10.1.0-64-bit\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/../../../../include

 c:\mingw\mingw-10.1.0-64-bit\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/include-fixed

 c:\mingw\mingw-10.1.0-64-bit\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include

End of search list.

GNU C17 (MinGW-W64 x86_64-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) version 10.1.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)

    compiled by GNU C version 10.1.0, GMP version 6.2.0, MPFR version 4.0.2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.22.1-GMP



GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072

Compiler executable checksum: 21a8d9a0add79f637093bff9641d5f35

COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles\cmTC_a01cd.dir\CMakeCCompilerABI.c.obj' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'

 c:/mingw/mingw-10.1.0-64-bit/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_a01cd.dir\CMakeCCompilerABI.c.obj C:\Users\gvcal\AppData\Local\Temp\ccHRxkpy.s

GNU assembler version 2.34 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) using BFD version (Binutils for MinGW-W64 x86_64, built by Brecht Sanders) 2.34

COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/mingw-10.1.0-64-bit/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/;c:/mingw/mingw-10.1.0-64-bit/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/mingw-10.1.0-64-bit/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/

LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/mingw-10.1.0-64-bit/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/;c:/mingw/mingw-10.1.0-64-bit/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/mingw-10.1.0-64-bit/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/;c:/mingw/mingw-10.1.0-64-bit/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/../../../../lib/;c:/mingw/mingw-10.1.0-64-bit/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/mingw-10.1.0-64-bit/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/../../../

COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'CMakeFiles\cmTC_a01cd.dir\CMakeCCompilerABI.c.obj' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'

Linking C executable cmTC_a01cd.exe

"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\cmTC_a01cd.dir\link.txt --verbose=1

"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E rm -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_a01cd.dir/objects.a
CMAKE_AR-NOTFOUND cr CMakeFiles\cmTC_a01cd.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\cmTC_a01cd.dir\objects1.rsp
Error running link command: The system cannot find the file specified
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\cmTC_a01cd.dir\build.make:107: cmTC_a01cd.exe] Error 2

mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Libraries/Projects/CMakeTest/build/MinGW-10.1.0-64-bit/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

mingw32-make: *** [makefile:140: cmTC_a01cd/fast] Error 2





Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Libraries/Projects/CMakeTest/build/MinGW-10.1.0-64-bit/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/MinGW/MinGW-10.1.0-64-bit/bin/mingw32-make.exe cmTC_f77ee/fast && C:/MinGW/MinGW-10.1.0-64-bit/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_f77ee.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_f77ee.dir/build

mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Libraries/Projects/CMakeTest/build/MinGW-10.1.0-64-bit/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_f77ee.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj

C:\MinGW\MinGW-10.1.0-64-bit\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_f77ee.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c C:\Libraries\Projects\CMakeTest\build\MinGW-10.1.0-64-bit\debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c

Linking C executable cmTC_f77ee.exe

"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\cmTC_f77ee.dir\link.txt --verbose=1

"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E rm -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_f77ee.dir/objects.a
CMAKE_AR-NOTFOUND cr CMakeFiles\cmTC_f77ee.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\cmTC_f77ee.dir\objects1.rsp
Error running link command: The system cannot find the file specified
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\cmTC_f77ee.dir\build.make:108: cmTC_f77ee.exe] Error 2

mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Libraries/Projects/CMakeTest/build/MinGW-10.1.0-64-bit/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

mingw32-make: *** [makefile:140: cmTC_f77ee/fast] Error 2
```

My PATH and complete command line used:

Path:

```
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\MinGW\MinGW-10.1.0-64-bit\bin;C:\Users\gvcal\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
```

Command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" -Hc:/Libraries/Projects/CMakeTest -Bc:/Libraries/Projects/CMakeTest/build -G "MinGW Makefiles"
```

Comment: CMake can't seem to find `ar.exe`. Can you show what your `PATH` looks like (output of `ECHO %PATH%`) and what the complete CMake command line was you used?

Comment: @BrechtSanders added as requested. Its also worth noting that its happened twice now were CMake has told me it "cannot find a generator for MinGW Makefiles" when I clearly have your build in my path. After removing it from the path and adding it again it works once again both times, but it just seems rather strange to me... not sure if its related or not.

Comment: I tend to put the MinGW location much earlier in the path. 
Imagine for example in your case 'C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\' contains DLLs with the same name as in the MinGW, but one is 32-bit and the other is 64-bit? That has a potential to break things.

Why are you using `-H` instead of `-S` to specify the source location?

Not part of the issue here, but have you ever considered `-GNinja` and the use ninja instead of make? It is a lot faster.

Comment: I will put MinGW early on and see what happens! And these aren't commands I've typed in - they were generated by the CMake Tools extensions for VS Code! ;)

Comment: @BrechtSanders unfortunately that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @BrechtSanders I swapped to Ninja and everything is working now. I think this may be a bug with CMake and MinGW Makefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be a bug with CMake and MinGW Makefiles. Still not entirely sure what it is.

Anyways, I switched to the Ninja build system (https://ninja-build.org/) and all is working fine now.